# Strip HTML tags from validation errors

Tags: theming, services

I am using [Services 3.x](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) for creating web services for mobile application, and I am using the JSON format.

The validation errors given from the user register services comes with HTML tags; for example the *email already exists* error is the following one.

```
<em> the@email.com</em> is already in use.  Have you forgotten your password?".
```

How do I strip those HTML tags from the error message?

Answer (score 2):

[`hook_services_request_postprocess_alter()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21services%21docs%21services.alter.api.php/function/hook_services_request_postprocess_alter/7) looks like a good candidate. I don't have an installation to test with right now but something like this ought to work:

```
function MYMODULE_services_request_postprocess_alter($controller, $args, &$result) {
  if (isset($result['form_errors'])) {
    array_walk($result['form_errors'], function(&$error) {
      $error = strip_tags($error);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: `MYMODULE_services_request_postprocess does` not work but `MYMODULE_services_request_postprocess_alter` works for some of the endpoints. It worked for the default services in the module but not for custom services, I have created a custom services for user register login to save some extra data.

Comment: Oops, yeah it has _alter at the end you're right. I don't know about the custom services, in theory there shouldn't be any difference as the results all go through the same processing regardless of source module

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal 8 you can do it by using Markup:

```
use \Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup;
...    
$message = new TranslatableMarkup('<b>@message!</b>', array('@message' => 'A bold error'));
$form_state->setError($message);
```

OR

```
$mainMessage = "<em> the@email.com</em> is already in use.  Have you forgotten your password?";
$rendered_message = \Drupal\Core\Render\Markup::create($mainMessage);
\Drupal::messenger()->addMessage($rendered_message);
```